# Prevent Travis Python environment from pre-installing packages

Tags: python, pip, travis-ci, setup.py

Is there a way to prevent the Travis Python environment from pre-installing `pytest`, `nose`, `mock` etc.? The versions are old and causing order-dependent problems when upgrading. I want to specify my dependencies only in `setup.py`, but `pytest` and `py` require mutual upgrades, which seems to always fail.

I see there is a `virtualenv` key for `.travis.yml` which is sometimes mentioned briefly, but I don't see proper documentation for it.

Comment: Do you provide a `requirements.txt` file? What are the problems you're seeing?

Comment: No, I want to specify only in `setup.py`. Specifying versions for packages with mutual dependencies in `setup.py` leads to conflicts. Installing this way in a clean environment has no problems.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the convention? What conflicts? Again, could you provide a more specific problem? I have not experienced these conflicts running projects with `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` on Travis.

Comment: `pytest` needs upgrading, which needs a `py` upgrade. But `py` needs to upgrade `pytest`. I believe `setuptools` only does one at a time, so this cannot happen. The question is how to start with a clean environment (and if there is any documentation for the `virtualenv` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do this, but I found a relatively clean workaround: `virtualenvwrapper.sh` has a `wipeenv` command I did not previously know. So now I setup a "modern and clean" virtualenv like this:

```
before_install:
  - pip install -U pip setuptools virtualenvwrapper
  - source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)
  - wipeenv
```

I don't have to worry about the exact list of packages or intersection of them with my own, and the `install`/`script` sections can proceed unhindered by whatever Travis setup for me.